# How to keep items in Magento wishlist when sharing?

Tags: php, magento

Is there a way to keep the items in the wishlist when a user shares their wishlist? It is currently emptying the wishlist when a user shares.

Comment: May be this goes into the right direction and tells you where to search: http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.de/2012/02/keep-products-in-wishlist-after-adding.html

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. I managed to solve the issue.
In Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php I commented out the following line (#662 in my version):

//$wishlist->save();

This prevented the wishlist being emptied after sharing.

Comment: Thanks @matt  i have comment this line //$wishlist->save(); so it's working for me it will not empty my wishlist.